# Unable to understand a particular LDR command

Tags: arm, disassembly, ida

While attempting to disassemble my school library's book keeping app using IDA pro i came across this LDR statement which im not able to edit.

I wanted to increase the no. of pages of a particular book to a higher value so i found out the ARM instruction where it assigned the latter and changed it to a higher value.

Original:

```
LDR     R3, =(dword_8C46D0 - 0x3DBCDA)
```

When i tried to rename the address name to: 
`dword_8C43D4`

I received the following error message:

> Can't rename byte as 'dword_8C43D4' because the name has a reserved prefix.

So, what are these reserved prefixes and how do i tackle this problem?

Also, where can i get the short and informative tutorials for learning disassembly using ida pro?

Comment: Just use whatever hex value you want; not some label.  If you want 0x8c43d4, then you can use `ldr r3, =0x8c43d4`.  What is the meaning of 'dword_8C46D0'?  `LDR Rn,=value` just loads a 32bit value in the 'Rn'.  The arm opcode is only 32bit long so you can not load a 32bit constant (bits in the opcode mean other things like *add*, *sub*, etc).

Comment: ldr rD,=something is a pseudo instruction that the various assemblers support as artless noise mentioned is because you cannot load any 32 bit value you want as an immediate (in a 32 bit instruction 32+opcode+dest register spec cannot be less than or equal to 32).  the value on the right has to be something the assembler can compute into a number if it can do label math, okay.  if it can do any math at all, okay otherwise just a label or just a value.  that value is meant to be an address (a label) but they let you use an immediate value instead of a label string wherever I have used it.

Comment: you want info about ida pro, contact support.

Comment: @artlessnoise thankyou, so in my first line dword_8C46D0 is the label and hex value 0x3DBCDA is stored in it?

Comment: I don't know IDA Pro specifically, but I'd say it looks to have figured that the arbitrary 32-bit constant being loaded was an address, then decomposed that address into a massive negative offset from something it reckoned was a symbol. Sometimes tools can be _too_ clever...

Comment: @Notlikethat since i wanted it to load hex value 0x8C43D4 i modified it to LDR R3, =(dword_8C46D0 - 0x8C43D4) but still im getting the same error.

Comment: just change it to ldr r3,=0x8C43D4 then.

Comment: If you are tweaking the binary, the *code* `ldr r3,=0x8C46D0` is like, `ldr r3, [pc, #offset_constant]`  with `offset_constant: .word 0x8C46D0` (or the like).  You can just change  the 'offset_constant' to 0x8C43D4 (and 'offset_constant' is like dword_8C46D0)... but as *notlikethat* said the actually address seems to be subtracting something.  I think you can probably tell IDA pro not to be so 'intelligent'  the 'offset_constant' is somewhere and a hex editor search will find the value; if you know what it loads to r3.